# what's the name of a jquery scroll plugin like this

Tags: jquery

i need a scroll jquery plugin like this in this page :
Please see this page: http://studio-unit.co/photography/#photography-highlights
What is the name of this scroll plugins?
tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it ,
if any one need this full page scroll plugin check this link:
https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage